# Cannot install Lutris, stuck on dependencies that can't be installed?

Tags: apt

Every time I use apt-get or aptitude to install Lutris, no matter what I do to attempt to fix the missing dependencies, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lutris:i386 : Depends: python3-evdev:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-gi:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-requests:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-yaml:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-pil:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: gir1.2-notify-0.7:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: p7zip:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: fluid-soundfont-gs:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: x11-xserver-utils:i386 but it is not installable
               Depends: mesa-utils:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Even Aptitude is stuck:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install lutris:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lutris:i386{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1777 kB of archives. After unpacking 4628 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lutris:i386 : Depends: python3-evdev:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: python3-gi:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: python3-requests:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: python3-yaml:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: python3-pil:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: gir1.2-notify-0.7:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: p7zip:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: fluid-soundfont-gs:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: x11-xserver-utils:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

               Depends: mesa-utils:i386 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     lutris:i386 [Not Installed]                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n

*** No more solutions available ***

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     lutris:i386 [Not Installed]
```

Really unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: I don't know your OS/release details, so can't start to look up where some of those packages are located to offer suggestions.. Some are community supported packages, so do you have 'universe' enabled?

Comment: This package exists in a PPA and is not packaged in Ubuntu itself.  You need to contact the PPA maintainers directly to ask that they fix their packaging issue.  They accept issues on GitHub here: <https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)